# Xcode not reading HTML content

Tags: html, xcode, swift, ibeacon

I am creating an interactive beacons app using Xcode and Beacondo. 
Beaconed allows me to build my app with Xcode, however, when I insert HTML content into beacondo, Xcode refuses to read it.

How can I convert HTML into Swift in order for Xcode to read it ?

Comment: What does it mean, "refuses to read it"?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have create a Swift-file or something that will be interpreted as Swift code. But HTML needs to be put in a html-file.

I would create the file outside XCode and then add it to XCode with "Add files to YOUR_PROJECT"